# Spring boot dependencies could not be resolved

Tags: spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea, gradle, intellij-14

I am creating gradle spring boot project in IntelliJ but I am not able to resolve few dependencies.

```
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
```

build.gradle looks like

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile "joda-time:joda-time:2.2"
    compile "log4j:log4j:1.2.16"
    compile "org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:1.3"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-core:5.0.2.RELEASE"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-context:3.0.2.RELEASE"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-web:3.0.4.RELEASE"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-webmvc:2.5.2"
    compile "org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0"
    compile "com.google.guava:guava:23.4-jre"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:1.5.6.RELEASE"
}
```

I have tried various versions of spring-boot dependencies but couldn't find what's missing. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you just miss the spring-boot plugin?

Comment: Stop mixing spring versions... You are mixing 5.0.2, 3.0.2 and 2.5.2 never mix versions of a framework.

Comment: In Spring Boot you should not even need to specify version for common dependencies. The gradle plugin will take care of version management for you, it will provide you with the correct (and compatible) versions.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to figure out things with wild guesses, use already available samples, like [this one](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.5.8.RELEASE/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-simple/build.gradle).

The best place to start is official Spring Boot [Getting Started Guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/) which also contains sample (and simple) build configuration for Gradle.

Comment: As an addition, a good way to start a Spring Boot project is by generating it at [start.spring.io](https://start.spring.io/). You can select Gradle option and add the starters you need, and it will generate the initial "builderplate".